# Xinerama = 1 loses theme

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, themes, xinerama

I am testing out 12.04 and am using Xinerama = 1 in xorg.conf.

When I do this, everything seems to work, except that some applications end up with strange looking buttons.

Please see this image:
[image]
[Click here for an enlargement of the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8lde.jpg)

As soon as I change the Xinerama to 0, I lose my quad screen, but all applications look normal again.

Why does this happen and is it possible to fix this?

I'm using gnome classic on Ubuntu 12.04 because I couldn't get Unity2D or Unity3D to work over 4 screens.

Comment: You need to include some more details. ATI or Nvidia(or other).  Model, etc.  It's a good question, and I hope it gets a solid answer.  We need details.

Comment: Thank you.  Since you noted Unity3d, my workaround doesn't work for you.  It can be accomplished with Xinerama if don't need compositing/effects, but you have to want to give up 3d.  I hope you get a proper answer.

Comment: To be honest, I don't mind giving up Unity3D and compositing/effects etc in order to get all 4 monitors working!

Comment: What does not work? Clarify this. Are the screens showed in the Nvidia settings tool?

Comment: Thanks, I've added clarification to the end of my question above.

Comment: Ubuntu display manager does not work with Nvidia, just with ATI. But you don't see the 2 more monitors in the settings area where you could move them around in Nvidias tool, don't you? _BTW_ the youtube video is not real it's just a design mockup. But you can connect as many monitors as you like and your graphic card supports.

Comment: I seem to be able to connect 2 monitors to 1 card, or 1 monitor each to each card.  Both methods work, I just can't connect all 4 monitors.

Comment: So if I return my nvidia cards and get ati cards, will it all work as it should?

Comment: Note that that 6 monitor demo was probably on an AMD Radeon Eyefinity card, which can support 6 DisplayPort outputs from a single card.  That is probably somewhat simpler to get working than 2 cards driving 2 monitors each.

Comment: @James Henstridge, point taken.  So how do I configure what I have?

Comment: I don't have any experience with doing what you want with multiple cards.  I was just pointing out that the 6 screen demo didn't necessarily imply that your problem was simple.

Comment: I have got the screens to work, but I seem to have a theme related problem which disappears as soon as I get rid of the quad screen and revert back to 1 screen.  It happens when I switch between xinerama = 1 and xinerama = 0.

Comment: Just to link your bug report for reference: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/994835

Answer (score 1):

It's a workaround for themes not applying in Cinammon with Xubuntu, but you could try: `setting a GTK3 theme as default in XFCE configs, and, login again in Cinnamon` from [here](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/209).

Different problem, but it might work to get the theme to apply.

I don't know what DE you're using, but it's definitely not Unity.

Comment: I'm using gnome classic on Ubuntu 12.04 because I couldn't get Unity2D or Unity3D to work over 4 screens.

Comment: you should add that data to your question